# osx, making tableview reloadable

Tags: objective-c, macos, tableview, nsarraycontroller, reloaddata

I have another simple question I can not solve by myself. I have two xibs. main.xib for the user input and result.xib for the results. Xib2 starts when a button is pushed on input-xib.
The button action (in AppDelegate.m):

```
- (IBAction)pushRun:(id)sender {

    if (!rwc)
    {
        rwc = [[ResultWindowController alloc] init];
    }
    [rwc setValueArray:[toDoItemArrayController arrangedObjects]];
    [rwc setNumberOfCalculations:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[_inputNumberOfCalculations intValue]]];
    [rwc calculateResults]; //starts method in 2nd-window controller for result calculation

    [rwc showWindow:self]; 
}
```

`rwc` is a `WindowController` doing the calculation and showing the result.xib (`ResultWindow`):

ResultWindowController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ResultWindowController : NSWindowController{

    NSArray *valueArray;
    NSMutableArray *resultArray;
    NSNumber *numberOfCalculations;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSArray *valueArray;
@property (retain) NSNumber *numberOfCalculations;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSMutableArray *resultArray;

-(void)calculateResults;

@end
```

ResultWindowController.m:

```
#import "ResultWindowController.h"
#import "ResultItem.h" //my result model

@implementation ResultWindowController
@synthesize valueArray, resultArray, numberOfCalculations;

- (id)init
{
    if(![super initWithWindowNibName:@"ResultWindow"])
    return nil;
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{

}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];
}

- (void)calculateResults
{
    //a lot of calculation code ...

    ResultItem *newResult = [[ResultItem alloc]init];

    [newResult setValue:[nameArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"name"];
    [newResult setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:avg] forKey:@"averageValue"];
    [newResult setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:min] forKey:@"minValue"];
    [newResult setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:max] forKey:@"maxValue"];
    [newResult setValue:dimensionRandomArray forKey:@"randomArray"];

    [resultArray addObject:newResult]; 

}
```

The results are put in an model-object and collected in the `resultArray`.
Now it's going to get interesting (at least for me):

1. the `resultArray` is bound as content to a `NSArrayController` via BindingInspector
2. the `NSArrayController` is part of the result.xib
3. the result.xib has a `tableview` (without own class or viewcontroller)
4. the `tableview` columns are bound to the `NSArrayController` via keyvalues used in the  `resultArray`

Everything works really fine when the result.xib window starts. The `tableview` shows the content as expected. BUT! When I make changes at the input.xib and push the action button again the `tableview` at the result.xib is not updating.
I checked the `resultArray` content (via NSLog) and it gets all the new values, so works fine.

WHERE IS MY PROBLEM?

I read a lot of `[tableView reloadData]` but I don't know how to actuallay set up the code and the necessary bindings for it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the object to your array, make an IBOutlet to your array controller, and use the method `addObject:` to add object's to your table view.

Comment: Hello TheAmateurProgrammer, do you mean I need to change `[resultArray addObject:newResult];` in `[resultArrayController addObject:newResult];` and create an outlet in `ResultWindowController`?